# Read Multiple files in awk and print each file separately one below another

Tags: shell, awk

I have a requirment to read multiple files as input and print each of them in a table format one below another.
My code is like below to send mail,

`echo "$(<file1)" | awk -F',' 'BEGIN{print "<table border=1    cellpadding=1  cellspacing=0    bordercolor=BLACK >"}{ print "<tr><td>"$1"</td><td>"$2"</td></tr>"} END { print "</table>" } ' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t`

file1:

```
101|ABC|XXX
102|CAF|YYY
```

file2:

```
104|RRR|gfd
106|ytr|rte
```

Output should be a table format like read above files and do some formatting then send mail with tables one below another.

Output in tabular format:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td2xb.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNYXc.png)

Comment: It would work better if you removed that trailing `)` and defined proper field separator for awk in `awk -F`. Tip: it's not comma. Also, no need for that `echo "$(<file1)" |`, awk takes files as parameter. Please, post the expected output of the awk command.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show the output is your current command producing. Your code looks plausible. `sendmail` is just confusing the issue. Get so `awk '{stuff....}' file file2 ... > tableFile.html` is working reliable, and then you worry about mailing as a seperate opportunity.

Comment: Post text, not links or images. We can't test a potential solution using an image.

Comment: And sorry, can't upvote a Question that uses links to illustrate expected output (hint, hint). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples input and expected output written in GNU `awk`. I have written logic how to generate a proper html, properties are taken from OP's tried code itself, if any further editing needed for table etc then one could edit this accordingly too. You could take this output into a output file and then could use `sendmail` to send this by email too.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
  print "<html>" ORS "<table border=1    cellpadding=1  cellspacing=0    bordercolor=BLACK >"
}
{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    print  "<td>"$i"</td>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
END{
  print "</table>" ORS "</html>"
}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, here the files will be variables, so we have to echo all files to awk. like                                                                                                                
echo "$(<test4)"  "$(<test3)" | sed 's/^+--.*//g' | awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
  print "<html>" ORS "<table border=1    cellpadding=1  cellspacing=0    bordercolor=BLACK >"
}
{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    print  "<td>"$i"</td>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
END{
  print "</table>" ORS "</html>"
}'  
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t

Comment: @Ravi : `sed 's/^+--.*//g'` = `awk '{gsub(/^+--/,"", $0)}'` So `awk '{....}] file1 file2 still applies. Awk can do just about anything that `sed` can do. `echo "$(< file)"` is crazy talk! ;=) Useful in some circumstances, but not what you have demonstrated here. OK? Good luck!